# Drush database issue

Tags: drush

I have encountered an issue with Drush, which doesn't show many commands that should be present. When I run a command with the `--debug` flag, I see the following error message.

> [Symfony\Component\Console\Exception\CommandNotFoundException] Command rq was not found. Drush was unable to query the database. As a result, many commands are unavailable. Re-run your command with `--debug` to see relevant log messages.

When I run `drush sql:connect`, it shows all the correct database information for the site.

I tried Drush 9.7.2, as well as Drush 10.2.2. Both versions return the same error, whenever I install Drush locally to the site, or globally.

I am trying the commands on Drupal 8.8.5, which runs on PHP 7.1.33, on macOS 10.14.6.

To add to the above, the site itself works fine. And again, these commands above show all the correct information, so it is clearly SEEING the database. This is a local (development) build, on my local machine, under MAMP 5.7.

Furthermore, when I run `drush site install -vvv`, I get the following error.

> [preflight] Config paths: /Users/[machine name]/vendor/drush/drush/drush.yml
> [preflight] Alias paths:
> [preflight] Commandfile search paths: /Users/[machine name]/vendor/drush/drush/src
> [debug] Bootstrap further to find site
> [debug] Trying to bootstrap as far as we can
> [debug] Done with bootstrap max in Application::bootstrapAndFind(): trying to find site again.
>
> In Application.php line 230:
>
> [Symfony\Component\Console\Exception\CommandNotFoundException] Command site was not found. Pass --root or a @siteAlias in order to run Drupal-specific commands.
>
> Exception trace:
> at /Users/[machine name]/vendor/drush/drush/src/Application.php:230
> Drush\Application->bootstrapAndFind() at /Users/[machine name]/vendor/drush/drush/src/Application.php:192
> Drush\Application->find() at /Users/[machine name]/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:235
> Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun() at /Users/[machine name]/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:147
> Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run() at /Users/[machine name]/vendor/drush/drush/src/Runtime/Runtime.php:118
> Drush\Runtime\Runtime->doRun() at /Users/[machine name]/vendor/drush/drush/src/Runtime/Runtime.php:49
> Drush\Runtime\Runtime->run() at /Users/[machine name]/vendor/drush/drush/drush.php:72
> require() at /Users/[machine name]/vendor/drush/drush/drush:4

It seems to say it can't find the site, which is understandable, as I am running the command to install a site.

Something is clearly wrong. I'm hoping someone can help me sort this out.

The output of `drush list` is the following.

> Drush Commandline Tool 10.2.2
>
> Run `drush help [command]` to view command-specific help.  Run `drush topic` to read even more documentation.
>
> Available commands:
> _global:browse     Display a link to a given path or open link in a browser.
> drupal:directory   Return the filesystem path for moddules/themes and other key folders.
> entity:updates     Apply pending entity schema updates.
> generate           Generate boilerplate code for  modules/plugins/services etc.
> help               Display usage details for a command.
> list               List available commands.
> pm:security        Check Drupal Composer packages for pending  security updates.
> runserver          Runs PHP's built-in http server for development.
> updatedb           Apply any database updates required (as with  running update.php).
> updatedb:status    List any pending database updates.
> user:login         Display a one time login link for user ID 1, or another user.
> version            Show Drush version.
> cache:clear        Clear a specific cache, or all Drupal caches.
> cache:get          Fetch a cached object and display it.             > cache:rebuild      Rebuild a Drupal 8 site.
> cache:set          Cache an object expressed in JSON or var_export() format.
> cache:tags         Invalidate by cache tags.
> config:import      Import config from a config directory.            > config:pull        Export and transfer config from one environment to another.
> core:edit          Edit drushrc, site alias, and Drupal settings.php files.
> core:init          Enrich the bash startup file with bash aliases and a smart command prompt.
> core:rsync         Rsync Drupal code or files to/from another server using ssh.
> core:status        An overview of the environment - Drush and Drupal.
> core:topic         Read detailed documentation on a given topic.
> php:eval           Evaluate arbitrary php code after bootstrapping Drupal (if available).
> php:script         Run php a script after a full Drupal bootstrap.
> site:alias         Show site alias details, or a list of available site aliases.
> site:alias-convert Convert legacy site alias files to the new yml format.
> site:install       Install Drupal along with modules/themes/configuration/profile.
> site:set           Set a site alias that will persist for the  current session.
> site:ssh           Connect to a Drupal site's server via SSH, and optionally run a shell command.
> sql:cli            Open a SQL command-line interface using Drupal's credentials.
> sql:connect        A string for connecting to the DB.
> sql:create         Create a database.
> sql:drop           Drop all tables in a given database.
> sql:dump           Exports the Drupal DB as SQL using mysqldump or equivalent.
> sql:query          Execute a query against a database.
> sql:sync           Copy DB data from a source site to a target site.

There are commands missing from the list. It appears that Drush is not connecting to the database, which is weird, because it clearly sees the database, it's clearly aware of the necessary credentials to make the connection, and Drupal itself is connecting. The commands that show up on the DRUSH LIST seem to work fine, for example `drush pm:security`.

> [warning] One or more of your dependencies has an outstanding security update.
> [notice] Try running: composer require drupal/core drupal/webform --update-with-dependencies
> [notice] If that fails due to a conflict then you must update one or more root dependencies.
>
> | Name | Installed Version |
> | --- | --- |
> | drupal/core | 8.8.4 |
> | drupal/webform | 5.9.0 |

I'm confused on what the solution is.

This is the output of `drush cr`.

> In Connection.php line 416:
> SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory
>
> `cache:rebuild [--cache-clear [CACHE-CLEAR]] [--no-cache-clear] [-h|--help] [-q|--quiet] [-v|vv|vvv|--verbose] [-V|--version] [--ansi] [--no-ansi] [-n|--no-interaction] [-d|--debug] [-y|--yes] [--no] [--remote-host REMOTE-HOST] [--remote-user REMOTE-USER] [-r|--root ROOT] [-l|--uri URI] [--simulate] [--pipe] [-D|--define DEFINE] [--notify] [--druplicon] [--xh-link XH-LINK] [--] <command>`

This is the output of `drush cr --debug`.

> Using the Drush script found at /Users/brianeller-mini/vendor/drush/drush/drush using proc_open
> [preflight] Config paths: /Users/brianeller-mini/vendor/drush/drush/drush.yml
> [preflight] Alias paths: /Users/brianeller-mini/Projects/various/docroot/drush/sites,/Users/brianeller-mini/Projects/various/drush/sites
> [preflight] Commandfile search paths: /Users/brianeller-mini/vendor/drush/drush/src
> [debug] Starting bootstrap to site
> [debug] Drush bootstrap phase 2
> [debug] Try to validate bootstrap phase 2
> [debug] Try to validate bootstrap phase 2
> [debug] Try to bootstrap at phase 2
> [debug] Drush bootstrap phase: bootstrapDrupalRoot()
> [debug] Change working directory to /Users/brianeller-mini/Projects/various/docroot
> [debug] Initialized Drupal 8.8.4 root directory at /Users/brianeller-mini/Projects/various/docroot
> [debug] Try to validate bootstrap phase 2
> [debug] Try to bootstrap at phase 2
> [debug] Drush bootstrap phase: bootstrapDrupalSite()
> [debug] Initialized Drupal site default at sites/default

In Connection.php line 416:

> [PDOException (2002)]
> SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory

Exception trace:

> at /Users/brianeller-mini/Projects/various/docroot/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Database/Driver/mysql/Connection.php:416
> PDO->__construct() at /Users/brianeller-mini/Projects/various/docroot/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Database/Driver/mysql/Connection.php:416
> Drupal\Core\Database\Driver\mysql\Connection::open() at /Users/brianeller-mini/Projects/various/docroot/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Database/Database.php:371
> Drupal\Core\Database\Database::openConnection() at /Users/brianeller-mini/Projects/various/docroot/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Database/Database.php:166
> Drupal\Core\Database\Database::getConnection() at n/a:n/a call_user_func_array() at /Users/brianeller-mini/Projects/various/docroot/core/lib/Drupal/Component/DependencyInjection/PhpArrayContainer.php:79
> Drupal\Component\DependencyInjection\PhpArrayContainer->createService() at /Users/brianeller-mini/Projects/various/docroot/core/lib/Drupal/Component/DependencyInjection/Container.php:173
> Drupal\Component\DependencyInjection\Container->get() at /Users/brianeller-mini/Projects/various/docroot/core/lib/Drupal/Component/DependencyInjection/PhpArrayContainer.php:265
> Drupal\Component\DependencyInjection\PhpArrayContainer->resolveServicesAndParameters() at /Users/brianeller-mini/Projects/various/docroot/core/lib/Drupal/Component/DependencyInjection/PhpArrayContainer.php:62
> Drupal\Component\DependencyInjection\PhpArrayContainer->createService() at /Users/brianeller-mini/Projects/various/docroot/core/lib/Drupal/Component/DependencyInjection/Container.php:173
> Drupal\Component\DependencyInjection\Container->get() at /Users/brianeller-mini/Projects/various/docroot/core/lib/Drupal/Core/DrupalKernel.php:544
> Drupal\Core\DrupalKernel->getCachedContainerDefinition() at /Users/brianeller-mini/Projects/various/docroot/core/lib/Drupal/Core/DrupalKernel.php:896
> Drupal\Core\DrupalKernel->initializeContainer() at /Users/brianeller-mini/Projects/various/docroot/core/lib/Drupal/Core/DrupalKernel.php:477
> Drupal\Core\DrupalKernel->boot() at /Users/brianeller-mini/Projects/various/docroot/core/includes/utility.inc:38
> drupal_rebuild() at /Users/brianeller-mini/vendor/drush/drush/src/Commands/core/CacheCommands.php:221
> Drush\Commands\core\CacheCommands->rebuild() at n/a:n/a
> call_user_func_array() at /Users/brianeller-mini/vendor/consolidation/annotated-command/src/CommandProcessor.php:257
> Consolidation\AnnotatedCommand\CommandProcessor->runCommandCallback() at /Users/brianeller-mini/vendor/consolidation/annotated-command/src/CommandProcessor.php:212
> Consolidation\AnnotatedCommand\CommandProcessor->validateRunAndAlter() at /Users/brianeller-mini/vendor/consolidation/annotated-command/src/CommandProcessor.php:178
> Consolidation\AnnotatedCommand\CommandProcessor->process() at /Users/brianeller-mini/vendor/consolidation/annotated-command/src/AnnotatedCommand.php:302
> Consolidation\AnnotatedCommand\AnnotatedCommand->execute() at /Users/brianeller-mini/Projects/various/vendor/symfony/console/Command/Command.php:255
> Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run() at /Users/brianeller-mini/Projects/various/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:1000
> Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRunCommand() at /Users/brianeller-mini/Projects/various/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:255
> Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun() at /Users/brianeller-mini/Projects/various/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:148
> Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run() at /Users/brianeller-mini/vendor/drush/drush/src/Runtime/Runtime.php:118
> Drush\Runtime\Runtime->doRun() at /Users/brianeller-mini/vendor/drush/drush/src/Runtime/Runtime.php:49
> Drush\Runtime\Runtime->run() at /Users/brianeller-mini/vendor/drush/drush/drush.php:72
> require() at /Users/brianeller-mini/vendor/drush/drush/drush:4
>
> `cache:rebuild [--cache-clear [CACHE-CLEAR]] [--no-cache-clear] [-h|--help] [-q|--quiet] [-v|vv|vvv|--verbose] [-V|--version] [--ansi] [--no-ansi] [-n|--no-interaction] [-d|--debug] [-y|--yes] [--no] [--remote-host REMOTE-HOST] [--remote-user REMOTE-USER] [-r|--root ROOT] [-l|--uri URI] [--simulate] [--pipe] [-D|--define DEFINE] [--notify] [--druplicon] [--xh-link XH-LINK] [--] <command>`

Comment: Moshe has sent you here, https://github.com/drush-ops/drush/issues/4404. Though I still don't get how to reproduce this issue. What exact command did you enter? So when you run `drush cr --debug` the error occurs and when you run `drush cr` it doesn't yeah? How did you install your site? How did you install Drush? Please update your question and help us to reproduce this error. Many thanks

Comment: In stead of saying that `drush sql:connect` and `drush status` returns the correct information, show us the output. (You can mask the password if that is your concern.) And there is no "site" command - it's "site:install" ;-) Just remove that from your post. Anyway, my first guess is that you are missing the needed database modules when running PHP as CLI, not through the webserver. (the output from `drush status` would have told us something about this.) Does `php -m` return mysqli and pdo_mysql?

Comment: Check "which php" command in terminal it should not show usr/bin/php since this issue is because of wrong php path update the bash profile with the correct php path which you are using for the project.

Comment: @Kumaresan Welcome to Drupal Answers! Is there anything that makes you think the PHP path is wrong? Supposing the OP has PHP installed in two different directories, and both the PHP versions are supported by Drush, how can you say the PHP path is wrong? I take the PHP version is supported by Drush, or Drush would show some PHP errors.

Answer (score 0):

You might be missing the global drush which is causing this issue.
Try to install drush globally in the following path where the composer is installed -
*C* or *D:\Users<username>\AppData\Roaming\Composer*

Add the following lines to your *composer.json* file :-

```
"drush/drush": "9.x"
```

and run

```
composer global update
```

Alternately you can also run

```
composer global require drush/drush:9.x
```

Update the path to global drush in ENV variables. Your path to drush would be :-
[image: path_to_drush]

Restart your Apache or open a new terminal window to check the *drush status*.